# How can I separate my flutter firebase/firestore implementation and providers to a independent package or library?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Currently, I am developing a flutter web app using Provider and Firebase. I would like to develop others apps (for example and admin console) with the same database and data providers.

My app currently have the following folders

```
my_app
  - models
  - providers
  - services (firebase/firestore crud)
  - pages
  - utils
  - widgets
```

I would like to have models, providers, and services as a local package or library. Something like:

```
my_lib
  - models
  - providers
  - services
my_app
  - pages
  - utils
  - widgets
my_other_app
  - pages
  - utils
  - widgets
```

First, I don't know how to create a local lib, and how to make it a dependency of my_apps.

Second, since I will be using Firebase and Firestorage on my_lib, I don't know how the instances initialized in main are used by the package. Is it enough to initiate the global variables on the my_lib?

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder you can create a folder packages and then create your 'packages`using`flutter create --template=package  my_package`,

Have your app can depend on it in pubspec.yaml

```
 my_package:
   path: ../packages/my_package
```

in this case you will have

```
 - my_project
    -lib
    -packages
      - my_package
```

This works well when its just your app depending on the packages.

If you need to access your packages in different projects you can use github/gitlab to host your packages .

Say you have two repos that need to share a private package, my_app and my_admin , you can create a new repo my_packages and have your packages in it I.E

```
 - my_packages
   - package1
   - package2
```

in your apps you can now depend on the packages using git eg

```
 package1:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:username/my_packges.git
      ref: main // branch
      path: ./package1 //package name
package2:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:username/my_packges.git
      ref: main // branch
      path: ./package2 //package name
```

For github you need [ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Comment: excellent answer. The only thing I am missing is understanding how packages will access the FirebaseFirestore.instace from the projects.

Comment: Thats the neat part , your apps dont need to know you are using firebase,( ofcourse you have to setup firebase),  other than that you have a stream that fetches users , in the app you just subscribe to the stream . you can check flutter_bloc repo for demos https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples

Comment: let me see if I understand. In my case, I am using provider. I will have all Firebase/Firestore CRUD operation implemented on my private "my_package' shared with different apps as you explained. So, it will be enough to set up Firebase in each app? Where should do "await Firebase.initializeApp()"? Do I have to do something else on the package to get the instances?

Comment: Yes you're correct .`Firebase.initializeApp()`  just in the app, in the packages no need

Comment: In the packages just do your CRUD to firestore as usual